# A simple recipe page in HTML, SASS and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I've been learning how to design responsive webpages. I got done the basics and can create code that closely resembles the design, but I was wondering what are the best practices in web development when it comes to the following points:

- What units in CSS are considered best practices when developing webpages ? I try to use `rem`, `%` and `vh` wherever possible but what are the cases when it can be given in absolute units ?
- If design specification are given in pixel, how does one generally go about converting it to a responsive design that'll work on most of the screen sizes ?
- I've tried to add a functionality where when the recipe ingredient text is clicked the corresponding checkbox get's ticked/unticked is the JS code attached below a good way to achieve this ?
- What other structuring changes can be done to the following code to bring it up to standard ?

I've added a [working CodePen here](https://codepen.io/shinx32/pen/abLppaw). A hosted version of the page can be found [here](https://dev-challenges-recipie.web.app/). Also pasting the code here:

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,
  maximum-scale=5" />
    <link rel="icon" href="devchallenges.png" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://devchallenges.io/" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/141eeabd6d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;500&family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Devchallenges</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="board">
        <header>
            <h1>Classic Cheesecake Recipe</h1>
            <div class="header-desc">
                <div><img src="6dots.svg"></div>
                <div>Look no further for a creamy and ultra smooth classic cheesecake recipe! Paired with a buttery graham cracker crust, no one can deny its simple decadence. For the best results, bake in a water bath.</div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="main-pic"><img src="photo1.png" alt="A slice of cheesecake"></div>
        <div class="details-panel">
            <div class="instructions-panel">
                <div class="recipie-ingredients">
                    <h2>Ingredients</h2>
                    <h3>Graham Cracker Crust</h3>
                    <div class="ingredients-point">
                        <div><input type="checkbox" class="checkmark"></div>
                        <p>1 and 1/2 cups (150g) <strong>graham cracker crumbs</strong> (about 10 full sheet graham crackers)</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ingredients-point">
                        <div><input type="checkbox" class="checkmark"></div>
                        <p>5 Tablespoons (70g) <strong>unsalted butter, melted</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ingredients-point">
                        <div><input type="checkbox" class="checkmark"></div>
                        <p>1/4 cup (50g) <strong>granulated sugar</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Cheesecake</h3>
                    <div class="ingredients-point">
                        <div><input type="checkbox" class="checkmark"></div>
                        <p>four 8-ounce blocks (904g) full-fat <strong>cream cheese</strong>, softened to room temperature</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ingredients-point">
                        <div><input type="checkbox" class="checkmark"></div>
                        <p>1 cup (200g) <strong>granulated sugar</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ingredients-point">
                        <div><input type="checkbox" class="checkmark"></div>
                        <p>1 cup (240g) full-fat <strong>sour cream</strong>, at room temperature</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ingredients-point">
                        <div><input type="checkbox" class="checkmark"></div>
                        <p>1 teaspoon <strong>pure vanilla extract</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ingredients-point">
                        <div><input type="checkbox" class="checkmark"></div>
                        <p>2 teaspoons <strong>fresh lemon juice</strong> (optional, but recommended)</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ingredients-point">
                        <div><input type="checkbox" class="checkmark"></div>
                        <p>3 large <strong>eggs</strong>, at room temperature</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ingredients-point">
                        <div><input type="checkbox" class="checkmark"></div>
                        <p>topping suggestions: <em>salted caramel, lemon curd, strawberry topping, chocolate ganache, red wine chocolate ganache, fresh fruit, whipped cream, or raspberry sauce (recipe in notes)</em></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2>Instructions</h2>
                    <div class="instruction-line">
                        <div>
                            <div class="numbering">1</div>
                            <div class="instruction">Adjust the oven rack to the lower-middle position and preheat oven to 350°F (177°C).</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="numbering">2</div>
                            <div class="instruction"><strong>Make the crust:</strong> Using a food processor, pulse the graham crackers into crumbs. Pour into a medium bowl and stir in sugar and melted butter until combined. (You can also pulse it all together in the food processor.)
                                Mixture will be sandy. Press firmly into the bottom and slightly up the sides of a 9-inch or 10-inch springform pan. No need to grease the pan first. I use the bottom of a measuring cup to pack the crust down tightly. Pre-bake
                                for 8 minutes. Remove from the oven and place the hot pan on a large piece of aluminum foil. The foil will wrap around the pan for the water bath in step 4. Allow crust to slightly codiv as you prepare the filling.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="numbering">3</div>
                            <div class="instruction"><strong>Make the filling:</strong> Using a handheld or stand mixer fitted with a paddle attachment, beat the cream cheese and granulated sugar together on medium-high speed in a large bowl until the mixture is smooth and creamy,
                                about 2 minutes. Add the sour cream, vanilla extract, and lemon juice then beat until fully combined. On medium speed, add the eggs one at a time, beating after each addition until just blended. After the final egg is incorporated
                                into the batter, stop mixing. To help prevent the cheesecake from deflating and cracking as it cools, avoid over-mixing the batter as best you can.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="numbering">4</div>
                            <div class="instruction"><strong>Prepare the simple water bath (see note)</strong> Boil a pot of water. You need 1 inch of water in your roasting pan for the water bath, so make sure you boil enough. I use an entire kettle of hot water. As the water
                                is heating up, wrap the aluminum foil around the springform pan. Pour the cheesecake batter on top of the crust. Use a rubber spatula or spoon to smooth it into an even layer. Place the pan inside of a large roasting pan.
                                Carefully pour the hot water inside of the pan and place in the oven. (Or you can place the roasting pan in the oven first, then pour the hot water in. Whichever is easier for you.)</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="numbering">5</div>
                            <div class="instruction">Prepare the simple water bath (see note) Boil a pot of water. You need 1 inch of water in your roasting pan for the water bath, so make sure you boil enough. I use an entire kettle of hot water. As the water is heating up,
                                wrap the aluminum foil around the springform pan. Pour the cheesecake batter on top of the crust. Use a rubber spatula or spoon to smooth it into an even layer. Place the pan inside of a large roasting pan. Carefully pour
                                the hot water inside of the pan and place in the oven. (Or you can place the roasting pan in the oven first, then pour the hot water in. Whichever is easier for you.)</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="numbering">6</div>
                            <div class="instruction">Use a knife to loosen the chilled cheesecake from the rim of the springform pan, then remove the rim. Using a clean sharp knife, cut into slices for serving. For neat slices, wipe the knife clean and dip into warm water between
                                each slice.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="numbering">7</div>
                            <div class="instruction">Serve cheesecake with desired toppings. Cover and store leftover cheesecake in the refrigerator for up to 5 days.</div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="timing-serving">
                <div class="timing-serving-item"><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i>
                    <div><span>Yields</span><span>12 servings</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="timing-serving-item"><i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                    <div><span>Prep Time</span><span>45 minutes</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="timing-serving-item"><i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                    <div><span>Cook Time</span><span>1 hour</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="timing-serving-item"><i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                    <div><span>Total Time</span><span>7,75 hours</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

#### SASS

```
$header-font:'Playfair Display',serif;
$para-font: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
$max-board-width: 970px;
@mixin icon-style {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.board {
    font-family: $para-font;
    max-width: $max-board-width;
    width: 80vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    header {
        h1 {
            font-family: $header-font;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 3rem;
            margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
        }
        .header-desc {
            display: flex;
            align-items: flex-start;
            font-style: italic;
            font-weight: 300;
            div {
                margin: 0.5em 0.2em;
            }
        }
    }
    .main-pic img {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 1.5rem 0;
    }
}

.details-panel {
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    h2 {
        font-family: $header-font;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    h3 {
        font-family: $header-font;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
}

.timing-serving {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 12px;
    align-self: flex-start;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    // height: 40%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-items: space-around;
    .timing-serving-item {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-items: space-between;
        padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
        .fas {
            @include icon-style();
        }
        .far {
            @include icon-style()
        }
        div {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            span:first-child {
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 0.7rem;
                line-height: 0.9rem;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                /* Gray 4 */
                color: #BDBDBD;
            }
            span:last-child {
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-size: 0.8rem;
                line-height: 1.2rem;
                /* identical to box height */
                /* Gray 1 */
                color: #333333;
            }
        }
    }
    .timing-serving-item:first-child {
        i {
            color: #F2994A;
        }
        span:last-child {
            color: #F2994A;
        }
    }
}

.instructions-panel {
    width: 60%;
}

.instruction-line {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 0.7rem;
    &>div {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
        column-gap: 1rem;
        .numbering {
            // display: block;
            // width: 1rem;
            // height: 1rem;
            padding: 0.2rem 0.7rem 0.4rem 0.7rem;
            background-color: #F2994A;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Playfair Display;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 1.3rem;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 6px;
        }
        .instruction {
            strong {
                display: inline;
            }
        }
    }
}

.recipie-ingredients {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 0.2rem;
    .ingredients-point {
        display: flex;
        column-gap: 0.4rem;
        // align-items: flex-start;
        .checkmark {
            // display: inline-block;
            box-sizing: content-box;
            border: 1px solid #828282;
            border-radius: 4px;
            width: 1rem;
            height: 1rem;
            padding: 1rem 1rem;
            // float: left;
            //     margin-right: 1.2em;
        }
        p {
            margin: 0 0;
            display: inline-block;
            // float: left;
        }
    }
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    .board {
        width: 95vw;
        max-width: 95vw;
        header h1 {
            font-size: 1.7rem;
        }
        .header-desc {
            width: 96%;
        }
    }
    .details-panel {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
    .instructions-panel {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .timing-serving {
        // width: 90%;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        box-shadow: none;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        .timing-serving-item {
            padding: 1rem 0;
            flex-direction: 0 0 30%;
        }
        .timing-serving-item:first-child {
            flex: 1 0 100%;
        }
    }
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('.ingredients-point').click( (event) => {
        const clickedElement = $(event.target);
        if (clickedElement[0].className === 'checkmark'){
            return;
        };
        const targetElement = clickedElement.closest('.ingredients-point');

        let checkButton =  targetElement.find('.checkmark');
        if(checkButton.prop('checked')) {
            checkButton.prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            checkButton.prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```